# RDLC Report Parameter Error, even when it is defined

Tags: report, rdlc

I am getting a persistent error when I attempt to set RDLC report parameters.
The parameter is defined in the report, and I get this error when  I try to programatically  set the 
parameter.
An attempt was made to set a report parameter 'ReportParameter1' that is not defined in this report

The code I am using is:

```
ReportParameter p1 = new ReportParameter("ReportParameter1", Payments);
rep.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { p1 }); 
rep.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 2):

if you change path of report dynamic, remember reset it before change

```
reportViewer1.Reset();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code.I have used this code for my report

```
  // Add Parameter if you need
  List<ReportParameter> parameters = new List<ReportParameter>();
  parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("parameterName1", Parameter1Value));
  parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("parameterName2", Parameter2Value));
  ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(parameters);
  ReportViewer1.ShowParameterPrompts = false;
  ReportViewer1.ShowPromptAreaButton = false;
  ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

Parameter name should be same with report parameter,i think you already know that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while using vs 2010 Professional. But I managed to find the answer to that problem. It's simple vs checks to which report to assign the parameter and finds none so it throws the error. what you need to do is to load the report and then set the parameters.

Use the order as follows;

```
List<ReportParameter> parameters = new List<ReportParameter>();
  parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("parameterName1", Parameter1Value));
  parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("parameterName2", Parameter2Value));

  // Specify the report to load
  ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = YourReportPath;

  // Set parameters to the specified report
  ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(parameters);

  // Load the report
  this.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```